# Windows 10 | Hosts

Tags: windows, hosts

Trying to add record to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1 10.125.0.100
```

But seems no effect.

Also tried to add records like:

```
127.0.0.1 google.com
```

and result the same.

But if I'll add record like:

```
127.0.0.1 myself
```

It works, because my ping works with `myself` in this case.

What's wrong?

Comment: what do you mean `127.0.0.1 google.com` doesn't work? do you mean google.com still loads in your browser? maybe try a different browser?

Comment: With `127.0.0.1 google.com` added to the hosts file I can believe that maybe using Chrome it appears not to work 'immediately' due to perhaps existing connections, DNS resolver caching in Chrome but I would expect `ping google.com` to return 127.0.0.1, you don't mention this test specifically.

Comment: I solved trouble with domains throught "www." adding. But I still don't know what to do with `127.0.0.1 10.125.0.100`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried to add the following record to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`:
>
> `127.0.0.1` `10.125.0.100`
>
> But it seems to have no effect.

The Windows `hosts` file only maps IP addresses to hostnames e.g.:

```
127.0.0.1    google.com
127.0.0.1    www.google.com
```

It cannot redirect one IP to another (ex. `10.125.0.100` to `127.0.0.1`).

Comment: Add-NetNatStaticMapping is solution for windows.

Comment: Good solution. =)

Comment: I came up with the same problem. The answer is imprecise because hosts *can* redirect from one IP to another one this way. This worked for me in Windows 7 but not in 10. I wonder what changed.

Comment: @EstusFlask *"The answer is imprecise because hosts can redirect from one IP to another one this way. This worked for me in Windows 7 but not in 10."* - For clarity, I was referring to the Windows `hosts` file itself, which only maps IP and domain name combinations (and which hasn't changed in any version of Windows, as far as I am aware). It is of course possible to route one IP to another using different mechanisms in Windows.